# I am building a ship game using swift. Unable to detect collisions

Tags: ios, swift

I am building a ship game using swift. The objective is to avoid the incoming stones and score as many points as you can as the level increases. The stones come in opposite direction to hit the ship.But I am unable to detect collisions between ship and stone, stone passes through the ship.The ship can move to the left or to the right.

I used rect1.interects(rect2) for intersection.

Thank You.

here is ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var moveWater: MovingWater!

var boat:UIImageView!
var stone:UIImageView!
var boatLeftRight : UILongPressGestureRecognizer!

var tapTimer:Timer!

var leftM:UInt32 = 55
var rightM:UInt32 = 250

var leftS:UInt32 = 35
var rightS:UInt32 = 220

func startGame() {
    boat = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "boat"))
    boat.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 90)
    boat.frame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.height - boat.frame.size.height - 10
    boat.center.x = self.view.bounds.midX

    self.view.insertSubview(boat, aboveSubview: moveWater)

    boatLeftRight = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.leftRight(tap:)))
    boatLeftRight.minimumPressDuration = 0.001
    moveWater.addGestureRecognizer(boatLeftRight)



}

func leftRight(tap:UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {


    if tap.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended {
        if (tapTimer != nil)  {
            self.tapTimer.invalidate()
        }
    } else if tap.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {
        let touch = tap.location(in: moveWater)
        if touch.x > moveWater.frame.midX {
            tapTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(0.005), target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.moveBoat(time:)), userInfo: "right", repeats: true)

        } else {
            tapTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(0.005), target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.moveBoat(time:)), userInfo: "left", repeats: true)
        }
    }


}

func moveBoat(time:Timer) {

    if let d = time.userInfo as? String! {
        var bot2 = boat.frame

        if d == "right" {
            if bot2.origin.x < CGFloat(rightM) {
                bot2.origin.x += 2
            }



        } else {
            if bot2.origin.x > CGFloat(leftM) {
                bot2.origin.x -= 2

            }
        }
        boat.frame = bot2
    }



}

func movingStone() {


    stone = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "stones.png"))

    var stone2 = leftS + arc4random() % rightS


    stone.bounds = CGRect(x:10, y:10, width:81.0, height:124.0)
    stone.contentMode = .center;
    stone.layer.position = CGPoint(x: Int(stone2), y: 10)
    stone.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 3.142)


    self.view.insertSubview(stone, aboveSubview: moveWater)


    UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.stone.frame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.height + self.stone.frame.height + 10
    }) { (success:Bool) -> Void in

        self.stone.removeFromSuperview()
        self.movingStone()

    }



}
func update() {
if(boat.bounds.intersects(stone.bounds)) {
     boat.image = //set new image
  }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    moveWater.backgroundStart()
    startGame()
    movingStone()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: There are numerous problems I can see in your approach:
- missing main game loop where each game entity will get updated in regard to at least location
- mixing frame coordinates 
- collisions will have to be done from scratch, and uiview.bounds will not necessarily overlap with optimal from UX perspective collisions boxes
What I recommend is:
- find some tutorials how to design a game
- switch to SpriteKit which will give you physics for "free"

Comment: WHy can't I use collision detection. And I don't know why I am unable to detect collisions!

Comment: With frames you can easily detect rectangular shapes collisions only, if you make the collision rect small that's fine (smaller than your ship I reckon) , but you cannot detect custom shapes intersecting this way.

Comment: I did not get you and ya these are custom shapes. How to fix this?

Comment: By custom shapes I meant non-rectangular ones. You have a specialised collision detection API in SpriteKit so I highly recommend looking into it. That of course would require dropping your current approach with UIKit's views & frames, but it's a way to go if you're doing a 2d game.

Comment: Without using anything like SKit, can't I do?

Comment: You could create programmatically CGPaths for your non-rectangular game entities (like your ship) and then detect their intersections. Generating them will be really hard to do. If your ship would get a new image replacement a corresponding CGPath would be obsolete unless you generate it somehow dynamically. If you want stick with your current UIKit approach you will need an additional CGRect that will be bounding box used for collisions,probably smaller than UIView bounds for most game entities. The size of this new bounding box should be determined empirically to give plausible UX.

Comment: My last approach would be using rectangular collision boxes so it would probably work best for rectangular game entities. You could also consider more than one rectangular collision box for game entity in an attempt to simulate it's "real" shape.

Comment: I am very new to this language. May I know why if(boat.frame.intersects(stone.frame)) is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this myself. It was easy and without any SpriteKit, I have detected collisions.

```
   func intersectsAt(tap2 : Timer) {


    var f1 : CGRect!
    var f2 : CGRect!

    f1 = boat.layer.presentation()?.frame
    f2 = stone.layer.presentation()?.frame
    if(f1.intersects(f2)) {
        stopGame()

    }

}
```

Comment: Using timers is not a good practice for a game update loop and will cause you big issues in the long run.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Any reason you choose UIKit to make your game?

If you make a game you should really be using SpriteKit instead of UIKit.

Check google and youtube for SpriteKit tutorials, there is loads.

A really good start is this one that teaches you the basics of the SpriteKit Scene editor and how to do collisions etc.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/118225/introduction-sprite-kit-scene-editor

I recommend that you do not continue like this.

Hope this helps

Comment: I wanted to implement in a fundamental way. That's it, I will go ahead and use SpriteKit etc.

Comment: Yeah there is nothing directly wrong with what you are doing. But you might as well use the correct tools to make your game. It will make your life easier and will provide you with a lot more possibilities to make the game.

Comment: Hey, I got a doubt. How can I make the stone appear with respect to boat's position? Any idea? If the bot is to the left, the stone should appear left when it starts to animate and when it is towards the right the stone appears right.

Comment: You would create a boat SKSpriteNode and a stone SKSpriteNode. Than you can use SKActions to move things. In your case you would for example check the position of the boat Sprite and than spawn the stone sprite. e.g if boat.position.x < frame.midX { spawn stone on left } else { spawn stone on right }. You should watch some SpriteKit tutorials to get the basics down like adding SpriteNodes, using SKLabelNodes, using SKActions etc.

Comment: we cannot spawn using UIKit?

Comment: frame.midX ... what frame are you talking about? boat or stone frame?

Comment: By spawing I just meant creating / initialising the stone and adding it to the scene. Same for UIKit it would be creating the UIImageView and than adding it to the view controller. You really need to abandon UIKit completely and start from scratch if you want to make a game. You are using the wrong  tools and make your life harder.

Comment: frame.midX is a check in a SKScene you can use when making SpriteKit games. It gets the centre of the xAxis to check if boat is on left half or right  half of the screen.

Comment: I want to complete dis for my own satisfaction. I will starting using SKit. What do you mean by frame.midX which frame?

Comment: the frame of the SKScene. In UIKit you could say this in a UIViewController if boat.center.x < view.frame.midX {.... to check if boat position is on the left or right side of your screen.

Comment: Ya I got it,  but I cannot compare boat.pos.x with boat.midX right?

Comment: no, you would want to compare the boat position in relation the your UIViewController to get the centre of the screen. You said you want the stone to spawn on the left or right side of the boat depending where the boat is. So you would have a check like this to see if boat is on left or right side of screen and than spawn/add the stone.

Comment: Please feel free to ask another question if you have troubles.

Comment: if boat.center.x > view.frame.midX {
        
        stone.layer.position = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10)
        stone.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 3.142)
        } else if boat.center.x < view.frame.midX {
            stone.layer.position = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 10)
            stone.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 3.142)

        }


whats wron in this

Comment: I can't just look at this and tell you whats wrong. Please ask another question with proper code samples. Its getting of topic

Answer (score 2):

I saw your own answer.  This is basic collision detection indeed.  You should still have a look at SpriteKit.  I see that you are using a Timer, which is not the best way to go since Timers will give you performance issues in the long run.  It's a common mistake when you start game developement.

Maybe you think that you can ensure a frame rate by setting a very fast timer.  The thing is that timers are not consistent and they have low priority too.  This means that your timer call will be delayed if something more important happens in the background.  If your movement is based on that forced refresh rate, it will become choppy very quickly.  Also the code you run in the timer might get faster or slower depending on the logic you are using.

SpriteKit provides you with an update function that is run every frame and that let's you know about the current system time at every frame.  By keeping track of that value, you can then calculate how much time went between two frames and you can then scale your movement accordingly to compensate for the time difference between two frames.

On top of that SpriteKit offers you a bunch of options for collision detection and movement.  It integrates a very well made Physics Engine and collision detection system.  It will also do collision detection on complex shapes, apply forces to the bodies, etc.

I strongly suggest you follow the link to Ray Wenderlich's website given to you in the answer above.  If you have the budget, you might also want to buy their book on how to make 2D games for Apple devices.  I've read that cover to cover and I can say I love it.  I can now do my own stuff with SpriteKit and it's also a very good starter for newcomers to swift.

Comment: Ya I have gone through SpriteKit and all it was my implementation and I wanted to code in a basic way. Now I will definitely switch to gameEngines.

Thank You.

Comment: @PrasannaVigneshwar : you will see pretty quickly that SpriteKit is pretty much, for the basic stuff, like playing with legos.  XCode's editor lets you design a lot of stuff visually and even though it's not as mature as the Interface Builder, it's still well made and it lets you reuse a lot of things.  It's also very good to separate content and design from code, making things modular and reusable.

Comment: And while I'm thinking about it, it's still a bit of a mess, the integration with GameplayKit is another interesting thing to look at, especially if you are thinking of adding autonomous behaviour or procedural content to your game.  There are basic AI algorithms that are implemented in there as well as a complete state machine system, an entity-component-behaviour system, noise generating algorithms and even more.  I've been experimenting with that a lot.  Cruel lack of documentation for Swift, but lots of good stuff too!